# ExactTarget - Update hyperlink after email was sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking, url

ExactTarget - How to update hyperlink after email was sent?

We sent out an email. Later was told there's a change to one of the hyperlinks. How do I update that so subsequent click will point to the new URL? I couldn't find any in My Tracking > Tracking Details > Click Activity . BTW, I did not use "name" or "alias" attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of the June 2015 release, users with Account Administrator or Content Creator roles can now update links post-send. However, your send must allow for tracking click data.

Check out the [June 2015 release notes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/june_2015_release/#email) for a detailed explanation of how to update links post-send.

I hope this helps!

Kelly

Answer (score 0):

Currently, links can't be updated in the ExactTarget application but I believe ExactTarget Global Support may be able to fix that for you:

http://www.exacttarget.com/contact-exacttarget

Answer (score 0):

Slaesforce Exact target has a good feature, If we sent out an email or campaign. Later was told there's a change to one of the hyperlinks. Then we can update the new URL to perform below mentioned activity.

Activity to be perform : My Tracking > Select your Mail > Click Job Links > Change the Targeted URL.

Reference Link:

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_job_link.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_joblinks_overview.htm&type=5

Note: Text Only emails cannot be updated. New personalization strings and AMPscript variable references can't be added. Links older than 90 days old may not be available to edit